# Exiting Instruments "Full Screen"

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, instruments

I was doing a memory profile in Instruments for my iPhone app and I pressed the "Full Screen" button in the lower left.  The screen went black and I can't make it do anything else.  When I power cycle the box I get the splash screen appearing, and then it goes back to black.  Please help.

Here's a doc showing the button in the lower left.  "Full Screen"

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/ViewingandAnalyzingData/ViewingandAnalyzingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH5-SW6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by resetting the PRAM on the Mac.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this bug just one time, and I had to reboot to clear it. I'm confused that rebooting doesn't clear it for you; Instruments shouldn't be starting up or anything on reboot. My solution to things like this is to SSH into the box from another machine, look for Instruments with `ps -ef`, and kill it (but as I said, when I hit this, rebooting fixed it). If you have no other machine, this may be a good time to read ["Starting up in Safe Mode"](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1455), and then perhaps ["Recovering your entire system."](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/15638.html) Hope it doesn't come to that. Every developer should be using Time Machine plus a separate full-disk program like Carbon Copy Cloner or SuperDuper (I like SD myself). It's just too easy to tear up your machine doing the kinds of things we do, even when you think what you're doing is simple.